# XCode stopped symbolicating a specific app

Tags: ios, xcode, symbolicatecrash

Using XCode 8, it has a few archive apps that were submitted to the App Store, receiving crash reports.

Starting from two versions ago, it stopped symbolicating one of the apps on the Organizer, even though the archive is there.

Previous versions shows correctly and so are other apps.

When I symbolicate manually, it works well. So the crash info is there, archive is there, any idea why it stopped working?

Comment: Have you created the debug symbols? See _Debug Information Format_ in the _Build Settings_.

Comment: Yeap, `DWARF with DSYM file` is chosen.

Comment: I experience the same problem lately with Xcode 8. Any ideas yet?

Comment: I am starting to get a hunch but have no solution yet. I seems it worked for me until I started adding two CocoaPods (FontAwesome and AEXML) to the project. Could this also be true in your case?

Comment: No idea, it started working after some weeks / released versions.